# Is it possible to add a GameObject to an editor-only script that is meant to add new spawnnable items to menus?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It seems like getting reference to a prefab, mesh, or sprite from an editor script that is not attached to a GameObject is almost impossible. However, there must be a way to do it. I've thought about doing a folder search, but that seems unreliable. Any other options?

I've only tried attaching an object directly to the script - which returns null. (I'm assuming, there's nothing there to actually attach it to.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Completely unclear what you are asking for ... please include your code and maybe some screenshots of what you are trying to achieve ... In short: Of course there are and there are multiple ways of getting references to assets .. most straight forward would be to simply expose an [`ObjectField`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.ObjectField.html) in an [`EditorWindow`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.html) or use the current [`Selection.gameObjects`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Selection-gameObjects.html)

Answer (score 0):

So,you can use [AssetDatabase.FindAsset](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.FindAssets.html) and [AssetDatabase.LoadAssetsAtPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath.html) to load prefab what you want to spawn.
But I’m not clearly understand how prefab should be applied to the script.